# Laravel Writing Test cases to test Post Request

Tags: laravel, unit-testing

I have a checkout page which as multiple scenarios. I want to write a test case to check post request is not throwing error messages. I am novice in writing Test Cases.

I want to know is it possible to test Laravel Route with all the specs or test case.

I need some examples.

Checkout Page have Products which is events. Events I want to create every time with new dates every time to manually test. Can this created from the unit test cases?
Events have Voucher Codes and Discounts and Payment and Free Events all this I want to test with unit test case.

Comment: Laravel allows most things to be tested. Based on what you are stating, it feels like you need a Feature test where in you can check for a route, create new entries and assert if these entries were created in the database. 

For a simple feature test to check the routes you should check https://devdojo.com/devdojo/simple-laravel-route-testing 

This video should also help https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UjA-16diixc

and this playlist should also help https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLdXLsjL7A9k0esh2qNCtUMsGPLUWdLjHp

Also remember the docs are super helpful too.

Comment: You can definitely check my profile and you will see links to other questions about tests, also one related to exactly what you are asking, feel free to edit your question with a test you would like to do (try something and share the code)

Comment: I have gone through the youtube. I did not find it helpful. Thanks anyway